# Externalize classes in multiple jars

Tags: java, module, dependencies, bukkit

So i've been working on a project of mine which works in modules. A module is simply an abstract class which all the modules extend from and replace the empty methods they need to. No modules have public functions that arent defined in the abstract class and each function is called depending on specific events.

What i'd like to do is externalize each module (for this exemple ill refer to Autorole as an exemple module) into its own jar that the main class will fetch and use. That would allow for Autorole to be hotswapped/hot updated by simply replacing it's old jar file with the new one and reload the main program (rescan the jars in the modules folder and load them, without turning off the main program)

Edit1 : Very much like craftBukkit loads it's plugins

Currently my approach is to export each module as an executable jar and start it with a command using the runtime environment of the main program. (java -jar Autorole.jar for eg)

The main function of each module simply adds an instance of their module (here Autorole extended from the module class) into a static list in the main class of the main jar. And it works fine, its able to execute the Autorole jar properly and use it like it used to when everything was in the same jar.

But here comes the problem.
Autorole depends on the main class and thus has it as a dependency, and i dont know how to make it able to recognize the main file as their dependency, meaning right now i need to have a copy of the main class for each module which is far from convenient or optimized.

What i wanted to try at first was specify the path the main file is in but i got stuck rather quickly. The path cant be hardcoded since the main file has versions and modules arent version specific, plus the name might not be the exact same as expected, so i thought of passing the path of the main jar as a java arg, and that's where i'm at as i dont know what to do once i have the string in hands

tl-dr:
How can i load a jar from another like craftBukkit loads it's plugins

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The **Class Loaders** allow you to dynamically load classes into a JVM process. `URLClassLoader` is a class loader that loads classes from a given URL e.g. external jar on the file system.

Just call `ClassLoader#loadClass(String name)` with the fully qualified class name, e.g: `Class<*> theClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.packagename.ClassName");` and you will receive a `Class`. Then you'll have to get a constructor which you want to use to create this class's instance, e.g. `Constructor<*> theConstructor = theClass.getConstructor(String.class);` Finally invoke the constructor using `Constructor#newInstance(Object... initargs)` providing arguments required by the constructor.

Most likely, you will also want to set your plugin's class loader as a parent class loader.

Full example:

```java
URL[] jars = new URL[1];
jars[0] = new File("path/to/file.jar").toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jars, YourPlugin.java.getClassLoader());
Class<*> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.example.ClassName");
Object classInstance = loadedClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: After digging a bit into bukkit's source code i had found some classes mentionning URLClassLoaders but the classes were huge and i couldnt tell apart what was loading the class and what was specific to bukkit.

Thanks for providing an exemple, i'll try it as soon as i get enough time to

Thanks again!